# Header getting dropped in Laravel/PHPUnit Testing

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a laravel 5.x app and the unit testing was working all fine. Now the php unit has stopped sending headers with http request. One of my unit tests have the following code

```
 $content='';

    $content = $this->post('users/login', ['password' => 'mypass',
            'email' => 'james.bond@gmail.com'])->response->getContent();

   $data = json_decode($content);
   $token = $data->token;


  $content = $this->put('users/xsettings/0', ['HTTP_Authorization' => $token])->response->getContent();
```

I have checked the existence for `Authorization` at the receiving end and found that it is not in the request.

I have tried calling

> $this->refreshApplication()

and tried using

> $this->call(...)

without luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers are the 3rd parameter not the 2nd.

Try changing you're `PUT` request to be:

```
$content = $this->put('users/xsettings/0', [], ['HTTP_Authorization' => $token])->response->getContent();
```

Hope this helps!